# Excel conditional formatting of adjacent cells from a drop down list

Tags: excel, validation, formatting, conditional-statements

I've been searching around here but I can't find anything quite like what I'm after.

In excel I have one column with a drop down list of a dozen different initials, with conditional formatting on those cells. I would also like to format another column based on those initials, but don't want to set up a dozen rules on each cell, one by one. If I set up the top cell with the correct rules I cannot fill the formatting in because the formula is not updated on a row by row basis, but en bloc for the range.

I have no real experience with VBA or macro's, is there a way to do this more elegantly than brute force?

Thank you very much in advance. This forum has always been a great help, hopefully you can help this, too!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I'm not misunderstanding your question. You can copy the formatting to the other columns if you have set up the format as a formula. For example, if A is your column with initials, and you have a data cell in B2, then you can set a formula in B2 as A2="ER", for example, with the formatting you want, and do the same for the rest of your matches on A2.  Then, you can copy the format down column B (unfiltered) using Paste Special Format. You can copy the conditional formats across as long as you make sure that your format in the conditional formatting rule is anchored on column A (i.e., $A2="ER").

Comment: Thank you - I had formatted my anchoring wrong.  When I copied it over before it didn't work and I moved on, now it is right and it works!  Thank you kindly.